# Wagtail: Filter results of an InlinePanel ForeignKey

Tags: django, wagtail

These models allow me to establish multiple human "editors" for a tool:

```
class ToolPageEditors(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('people.UserProfile')
    page = ParentalKey('ToolPage', related_name='toolpage_editors')


class ToolPage(BaseAsset):
    content_panels = BaseAsset.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('toolpage_editors', label="Tool Editors")
    ]
```

But then each `ToolPageEditors` instance is a dropdown with more than 3,000 users. I'd like to limit the contents of that dropdown to people in a given group. I know how to do this in Django by overriding the admin form, but am having trouble figuring out how to accomplish it in Wagtail.

Suggestions? Thanks.

**Update:**

The key is `limit_choices_to`. Modified the class as follows and it works:

```
class ToolPageManagers(models.Model):
    def get_tool_editors():
        g = Group.objects.get(name='Tool Editors')
        return {'groups__in': [g, ]}

    person = models.ForeignKey('people.UserProfile',  limit_choices_to=get_tool_editors)
    page = ParentalKey('ToolPage', related_name='toolpage_editors')
```

Answer (score 3):

*Answer was put as an update to the original question, pasted below with some docs links.*

You can limit the available choices on a Django model's foreign key relationship by the kwarg [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Note: this will add a limit to the relationship, not just the choices available in the UI.

**Example code**

```py
class ToolPageManagers(models.Model):
    def get_tool_editors():
        g = Group.objects.get(name='Tool Editors')
        return {'groups__in': [g, ]}

    person = models.ForeignKey('people.UserProfile',  limit_choices_to=get_tool_editors)
    page = ParentalKey('ToolPage', related_name='toolpage_editors')
```

For more information about Wagtail's `InlinePanel` see the Wagtail docs - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels